# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'" trying to install Moka

Tags: apt, python, themes

I wanna install moka theme on my ubuntu with following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moka/stable
```

But get error:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

`python -V`: 2.7.6

`python3 -V`: 3.6.3

What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

See [zhazha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36232975/) on [python-dev installation error: ImportError: No module named apt_pkg - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13708180/875379) for a solution. In short:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```